# In online TFS how to see my shelve-sets and check-in

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Recently my project moved to online TFS before that we used server differed.
How can I see my shelve-sets and check-ins.

Please can anyone help to take my shelve-sets into my local machine.

Answer (score 3):

From the team explorer window Home screen

[image: Teameplorer home]

For Shelve Sets:
Click on Pending Changes, and then actions

[image: Pending Changes]

Click on Action and then choose Find Shelvesets, here you can search for shelvesets by user name, you can also see the same information through the web interface (at least you can with on premise TFS)
[image: Find Shelvesets]

You can then right click on a shelveset to download / delete etc.
[image: Manipulate shelveset]

For your changes:

From the Team explorer click on Source Control
right click on a folder, root or below and then click history. this will show you all of the changes that have occured, you can then drill down into each one to see the changeset that updated the files

[image: View History]